# Memory Stick connection

Tags: usb, 6.0-marshmallow, ram

Experia z3 with new marshmallow android has no option of sending data from the internal storage to a memory stick via USB cable.  with previous android it was possible. Is there any way to send data to a memory stick?

Answer (score 0):

Try with a file manager app such as ES File Explorer. It will show you folders in the internal memory, SD card as well as OTG usb connections. Just copy and paste to the required folder.